# Advice how to setup a complex login

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I have "complex" login structure, and I would love to use RxJs to handle the sequence, and give the rest of my app the login status...

This is how it works:

1. Fetch JWT Token from backend
2. Login to Firebase with token
3. Spread the JWT Token from the backend (contains roles etc) to subscribers
4. Redirect to Dashboard

I was wondering if I should use the error signal when login fails and complete signal when it completes, but I don't know if that's a good idea, since I would like to continue to send signals when the user logs out, and then logs in again, etc.

Any advice/tips on a good way of solving this?
(Right now I'm using this copy/paste code (*ugly*):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    public loginStatus$ = new EventEmitter<LoginStatus>();

    constructor(
        private http:Http,
        private jwtHelper: JwtHelper,
        private af: AngularFire,
        private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    ) {}

    login(username:string, password:string) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        let body = JSON.stringify({username, password});
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.http.post(environment.baseUri + "auth/fetch_token", body, {headers})
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    const authToken = response.json().auth_token;
                    const authTokenDecoded = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(authToken);
                    console.log(authTokenDecoded);
                    localStorage.setItem("auth_token", authToken);
                    this.auth.login(authToken, {
                        provider: AuthProviders.Custom,
                        method: AuthMethods.CustomToken
                    });
                    this.loginStatus$.emit(new LoginStatus(true,"Login successful"));
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.loginStatus$.error(new LoginStatus(false,"Unknown username or password."));
                }
            );
    }
}

export class LoginStatus {
    constructor(public status: boolean, public message: string) {}
}
```

Also, I would like to return an Observable from `login()` (feels *right*)

Answer (score 0):

Simply the HTTP request responds 401 (authorised) or success (200).

If 401 then router.naviagte to the login page.

If not then allow the user to go where they want.

On navigation to a different page you would fire off an /authorised request to check that the user is still authorised.

The only backend endpoint that does not require authorisation is the login endpoint itself. If user/pass is correct then set JWT cookie for all future requests (expire after 1 day?).

The client side implementation can easily use Observables (as can the backend implementation if you want to use RxJs server side).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but after a successful http request, I also have to sign in to firebase... I would like to chain these with RxJs if possible

Comment: the firebase stuff is hidden from Angular right? This Firebase stuff is done server side?

Comment: No, the firebase stuff is all Client-side :)

Comment: check out the function `this.auth.login(authToken, {xxx})` in the code over... Right now I don't handle if firebase authenticates or not (just assumes that that works correctly :S)

Comment: ok yes it easy to chain RxJs subscriptions using Angular. You need to use RxJs flatMap to flatten streams. I can point you to an example if it helps. Due to recent changes you now import flatmap with ... import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/publish'; (you will need the latter import too if done properly)

Comment: I have heard about flatMap, but I don't think that's what I need... I want to have a chain that *when* the first request complets, it changes (`switch` operator?) to the `this.af.auth` (an observable), **and** excutes `this.auth.login()` at the same time, and *then* when this.af.auth either throws an event (user object or undefined) I complete the login...

Comment: flatmap is used when you have 2 observables (AKA streams) and when the first stream emits, it emits to the subscribe of the second stream. this is obviously a straightforward scenario and things can get much more complex. Im afraid I cant offer help beyond flatmap im no RxJs expert. All the best. You may want to ask a question that reflects the contents of your last comment. That may get more attention.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should take a second look at flatMap! Also maybe reframe/refrase the question.. :)